# How can I create a double ssh tunnel with different methods of authentication?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have my local machine, host1 and host2.

- host2 is only accessible from host1
- I can access host1 from my local machine
- host1 is using a private key authentication method
- host2 is using a password
- host1 and host2 have different usernames
- I need to access a service running on port 1529 on host2 from my local machine

Thus, I can connect to host1 simply by:
`ssh -i path_to_key user1@3host1`

And to host2 from host1 by:
`sshpass -p 'my-pass' ssh user2@host2`

So far I have tried the command below with no success:

`ssh -i path_to_key -L 1529:host1:1529 user1@host1 sshpass -p 'my-pass' ssh -L 1529:host2:1529 user2@host2`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to SSH onto the second machine, reaching its service?

Sounds to me the easier would be to setup a tunnel on the first host, and query your service on host2 from there. In that case, you should be able to use:

```
ssh -i path_to_key -L 1529:host2:1529 user1@host1
```

Then, leaving that ssh running in background, from your workstation, something like `telnet localhost 1529` would forward your connection to `host2:1529`.